# Script install fonts powershell

Tags: powershell, fonts

I have a script which installs a font, after checking whether the fonts exists or not. However, I'm having trouble validating the existence of the font.

```
$FONTS = 0x14;

$FromPath = "c:\fonts";

$ObjShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;
$ObjFolder = $ObjShell.Namespace($FONTS);

$CopyOptions = 4 + 16;
$CopyFlag = [String]::Format("{0:x}", $CopyOptions);

foreach($File in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath)){
    If ((Test-Path "c:\windows\fonts\$($File.name)") -eq $False)
    { }
    Else
    {
        $CopyFlag = [String]::Format("{0:x}", $CopyOptions);
        $ObjFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname, $CopyOptions);

        New-ItemProperty -Name $File.fullname -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" -PropertyType string -Value $File 
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the error is in the (else), comes a message asking to replace the existing fonts . This should not happen because the (else) should install the fonts that do not exist !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong

```
If ((Test-Path "c:\windows\fonts\$($File.name)") -eq $False)
```

`Test-Path` returns `true` if the file exists and `false` if it doesnt. So in the case the file does not exist you have `false -eq false` = `true` so nothing is executed. Your code to copy the item only gets called if it already exists.

Solution:

```
If (Test-Path "c:\windows\fonts\$($File.name)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Paul is correct. Basically your If condition was backwards.

If (Test-Path "c:\windows\fonts\$($File.name)") 
 is equivalent to 
If ((Test-Path "c:\windows\fonts\$($File.name)") -eq $True)

Either will work, though the second is unnecessarily more complex.